# How to config target's build setting using CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocoapods

I'm trying to use CocoaPods with cocos2d template project. When I `pod install`, I get some warnings, like:

```
[!] The target `MyProject [Debug]` overrides the `ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

I don't wanna change cocos2d template project's build setting, so I modify the *Pods.xcconfig* to avoid the warnings. Later, I `pod install` again. And, all my modification gone! The *Pods.xcconfig* is overwritten by default values. CocosPods make me confused.

Anyone show me how to config CocosPods to work with a existing project?

Answer (score 1):

For the time being the xcconfing as the majority of the files in the Pods folder are generated from scratch after every installation. There is a feature planned to allow to edit the xcconfig which should land soon.